# Difference between @PropertySource and @DynamicPropertySource in Spring Framework

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The `@DynamicPropertySource` annotation was added as part of the release **5.2.5** of the Spring Framework. The [official  documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/DynamicPropertySource.html) says that:

> This annotation and its supporting infrastructure were originally
> designed to allow properties from Testcontainers based tests to be
> exposed easily to Spring integration tests. However, this feature may
> also be used with any form of external resource whose lifecycle is
> maintained outside the test's ApplicationContext.

There is also a basic example:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(...)
@Testcontainers 
class ExampleIntegrationTests { 
@Container 
static RedisContainer redis = new RedisContainer(); // ...
@DynamicPropertySource 
static void redisProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) { 
registry.add("redis.host", redis::getContainerIpAddress);
 registry.add("redis.port", redis::getMappedPort);
 } }
```

However, I don't understand... what's the use case for this new annotation when we have [@PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) that behaves in the same way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I eventually found the answer in [this Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24540) issue that led to the commit for the `@DynamicPropertySource` annotation.

The annotation `@PropertySource`:

> Is mainly used to read from property files using Spring Environment
> interface

Examples of its use can be found in [this nice article](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/).

`@DynamicPropertySource` instead is used to:

> make it easier to set configuration properties from something else
> that's bootstrapped as part of running an integration test.

This helps also setting up integration tests with [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org), getting rid of a lot of boilerplate code.

While the documentation is lacking in this case, a very good article can be found in [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/27/dynamicpropertysource-in-spring-framework-5-2-5-and-spring-boot-2-2-6) on the [spring.io](https://spring.io) website.
As per the article above, examples are:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ExampleIntegrationTests.Initializer.class)

class ExampleIntegrationTests {

    @Container
    static Neo4jContainer<?> neo4j = new Neo4jContainer<>();

    static class Initializer implements
            ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
            TestPropertyValues.of("spring.data.neo4j.uri=" + neo4j.getBoltUrl())
                    .applyTo(context.getEnvironment());
        }

    }

}
```

The `@DynamicPropertySource` annotation can make the test above clearer, eliminating the boiler plate code as you can see in the example below:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
class ExampleIntegrationTests {

    @Container
    static Neo4jContainer<?> neo4j = new Neo4jContainer<>();

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void neo4jProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.data.neo4j.uri", neo4j::getBoltUrl);
    }

}
```